# Audio problem with 14.04 and mp3

Tags: sound

I downloaded 14.04 onto computer with working 12.04. I have audio problem when I try to play mp3. The audio sounds like there are two sources running. It gives an echo sound. You tube audio works fine. I have installed restricked extras. How do I fix this? Thanks Jimmy